# There is no method to get the current background color of CardView

Tags: android, android-cardview

There is no method to get the current background color of CardView. There is a method to set the background like

```
cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(color);
```

I would like something like:

```
cardView.getCardBackgroundColor();
```

It will be really helpful.

Comment: The [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/cardview/src/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.java#296) shows exactly that method. Maybe it's a newer addition. Make sure you're using the newest version of the support library. -- Yeah, it's [relatively new](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/e7c701f05b4f6afa2913c3743638d7b25b96df83%5E%21/v7/cardview/src/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.java). Just update your library version.

Comment: @MikeM. wait whaaattt??

Comment: Actually, it returns a `ColorStateList`, so just call `getDefaultColor()` on that to get the normal background color.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you. Please post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with gradle. I was using an old version of CardView bundled with some other library. Fixed by adding the line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a `getCardBackgroundColor()` method has indeed been added to `CardView`, but in a rather recent version, so just make sure your support library version is up to date.

Do note that this method returns a `ColorStateList` rather than a single color value. Calling `getDefaultColor()` on that will give you the normal background color.

```
int backgroundColor = cardView.getCardBackgroundColor().getDefaultColor();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering.

Answer (score 0):

You should set and get color to parent layout inside CardView.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible">

</RelativeLayout>
```

In this case, try to set and get from RelativeLayout.

Comment: Sorry but that might look ugly in lower api versions, .